# Entity Framework 4.0 - Code only Reference

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am trying to learn EF 4 and its code only features. I tried the following great articles and was able to make a sample application.

http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2009/11/22/entity-framework-4-0-a-fresh-start-with-demo-application/#reply
http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/10/12/code-only-further-enhancements.aspx

But I am looking for a good reference library / website on Code only feature. I tried searching MSDN but couldn't find it.

Please help.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **[blog article](http://theminimalistdeveloper.com/how-to-map-to-existing-databases-in-entity-fr)** with fully working sample code in ASP.NET MVC 2 in a tutorial form that shows **how to use both EF 4.0 Code First and in conjunction with ASP.NET MVC 2**. It discusses advanced features of EF 4.0 Code First such as mapping to existing databases and customizing the standard conventions in EF 4 Code First.

The link: http://theminimalistdeveloper.com/how-to-map-to-existing-databases-in-entity-fr

Answer (score 3):

There might not be many of them yet. Code only is still in beta-stage and was not released with Visual Studio 2010 RTM. If you plan to use it in a productive environment you should consider using [fluent nhibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) or waiting to the final release.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/06/10/code-only.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/10/12/code-only-further-enhancements.aspx